# Windows 11 2FA prompt opens a console instead of a GUI window

Tags: windows-11, windows-hello, two-factor-authentication, yubikey, fido2

Some time ago, I started using FIDO2 keys (Yubikey 5 NFC, to be precise) as a form of second-factor authentication on a few sites that support it.

However, after some change in my system, most likely one of the Windows 11 updates in Autumn 2023, this has changed to something like:

Repro steps:

1. Go to a site where I have a FIDO2 key registered as a 2FA method. Example: https://dash.cloudflare.com/
2. Sign in with proper username and password (the 1st factor)

### Expected

A security prompt asking to "touch my security key" as a 2nd factor authentication:

[image: Expected experience for a FIDO2 2FA key]

### Actual

Instead, my Windows 11 now shows this:

[image: My current experience]

**Is anyone familiar with this area and has some idea how to restore the GUI version of the *Windows Security* prompt?**

I find it confusing and not very usable in some scenarios.

Comment: My suggestion would be to do an in-place repair of your Windows installation. If you have had this problem since October 2023, is there a reason, you haven’t tried to fix it before today?

Comment: @Ramhound In-place repair/upgrade seems unavailable in my OS, but thanks for the idea! I haven't tried to fix it because it's a low-priority annoyance. As a fallback, I could use other 2FA methods (typically, an Authenticator app or SMS)

Comment: Why is it unavailable?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 11 installer (ISO version) upgrade path ends with an error:

"The upgrade option isn't available if you start your computer using the installation media. (...)".

I wasn't able to resolve it. Of course, I could clean-install, but I'm looking for a more targeted solution here.

Comment: Launch setup.exe within Windows….

Comment: @Ramhound I did launch setup.exe (also tried all other *.exe files in the ISO image), the message seems misleading in this case. I guess I might try again when 24H1 build comes out.

Comment: You got the “The upgrade option isn't available if you start your computer using the installation media.”, from within Windows? That doesn’t make sense and waiting for 24H2 also doesn’t make sense nothing will change. We need more specific information to diagnose your problem